# Would it be better to have 10 GB PC5300 or 8 GB PC6400?

Tags: memory

My development machine is heavy on memory usage. It currently only has 4GB of PC5300. I'm going to buy 8 GB of RAM, but should I take out all my existing memory and install just PC6400 or leave some of the original and stick with 5300? I don't know if I'll ever need more than 8GB, I might, I'm just wondering if the speed difference between 5300 and 6400 is worth trashing the 2 or 3 GB of old RAM I would still have room for after adding the new RAM.

Comment: Why not just try it and see?  If you are buying the memory anyway a simple test will be more effective then us guessing.

Comment: Because PC5300 is cheaper than PC6400

Comment: What kind of development do you do? It's likely you won't notice a difference in speed between the two, because the hard drive will be the bottleneck anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If your job runs in 8gb, the faster 8gb will be a little faster.

If your job takes 9gb, the 10gb will be dramatically faster than the 8gb.

If your job takes 11gb, you'll need to test to see which is faster; it's likely but not certain that the 10gb would be faster than the 8gb.

If you're not sure, go for the larger amount of ram.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about cost, go cheap. Any RAM is faster than swapping to disk.